# How can i pass object from class thread to post?

Tags: c++

Hello on line 88 I get an error that says no matching function for call to `Post::Post(int&, std::string* [4], std::string* [4], std::string, const char [10])` and also candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided! I am not so good with C++ so I cannot understand what I am doing wrong! I want to pass objects from class `Thread` to class `Post`! Thank you very much.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Forum{

    private:

        string ForumName="Antikeimenostrafis programmatismos";

    public:
        Forum(){

        }
};

class Thread{

    public:
        string *postTitles[4];
        string *postCreatorNames[4];

        string _name;
        string _creator;
        string _date;


    public:



        Thread(string name, string creator, string date, int number){

            _name=name;
            _creator=creator;
            _date=date;

        }
        void NumberOfPost(){
            int noPosts=rand()%6;
            for(int i=0;i<noPosts;i++){

            }
        }

        public:
        string GenerateText(){
            string finaltext;
            static string texts1[]={"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.","Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.","It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.","It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.","The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.","Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.","Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."};
            static string texts2[]={"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.","Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.","It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.","It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.","The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.","Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.","Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."};
            static string texts3[]={"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.","Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.","It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.","It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.","The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.","Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.","Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."};

            finaltext+=texts1[rand()%6+10];
            finaltext+=texts2[rand()%6+10];
            finaltext+=texts3[rand()%6+10];

            return finaltext;
        }
};

class Post{

    private:
        int _id;
        string _title;
        string _creator;
        string _text;
        string _date;

    public:
        Thread* thread;

        Post(int id, string title,string creator, string text, string date){

            _id=id;
            _title=title;
            _creator=creator;
            _text=text;
            _date=date;
        }
        void postValue(){
            int PostID = 0;
            int ThreadNo = 1;
            int postNo = 0;

            Post tempPost = new Post(PostID, thread->postTitles,thread->postCreatorNames, thread->GenerateText(),"30-1-2017");
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error, you have the following constructor:

```
Post(int id, std::string title, std::string creator, std::string text, std::string date)
```

You are trying to call it with the following arguments:

```
Post(int&, std::string* [4], std::string* [4], std::string, const char [10])
```

The `int& -> int` conversion is allowed, as is the `const char[10] -> std::string`.
That leaves the `std::string*[4] -> std::string` conversion. That is *not* allowed.

Did you perhaps mean to pass `*thread->postTitles[0]` or somesuch?

Answer (score 0):

A second problem will occure as `new` instanciate the `Post` object but returns the pointer to the allocated memory. That means you have to change

```
Post tempPost = new Post(...)
```

to

```
Post * tempPost = new Post(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regrading the error.

Need changes some statements as given below.

```
string *postTitles[4];
string *postCreatorNames[4];

Post tempPost = new Post(PostID, thread->postTitles,thread->postCreatorNames, thread->GenerateText(),"30-1-2017");
```

to

```
string postTitles[4];
string postCreatorNames[4];

Post *tempPost = new Post(PostID, thread->postTitles[ThreadNo],thread->postCreatorNames[ThreadNo], thread->GenerateText(),"30-1-2017");
```

Hope this will work for you.